# Como animar a exibição de elementos de tamanho dinâmico somente com CSS?

Tags: html, css, animação, css-transições

Estou construindo um site que possui algumas transições de estados usando somente CSS. Em um deles o usuário clica no cabeçalho e a `div` abaixo exibe ou esconde. No outro há uma sequência de imagens e ao clicar na imagem corrente ele passa pra próxima. A técnica para ambos é semelhante: um `input` escondido com um ou mais `label`s ligados a ele, e os seletores CSS de "irmãos" (`+` e `~`). Exemplos:

1. Seções (usa *checkboxes* para esconder/mostrar cada seção)

```css
.escondido { display: none; }
.box { display: none; width: 200px; height: 100px; }
.escondido:checked + .box { display: block; }

h2 { width: 200px; background-color: lightgray; cursor: pointer; }
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<label for="aba1"><h2>Seção 1</h2></label>
<input id="aba1" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box a"></div>

<label for="aba2"><h2>Seção 2</h2></label>
<input id="aba2" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box b"></div>
```

2. Imagens (usa *radio buttons* para circular entre as imagens)

```css
.escondido { display: none; }
.imagem { display:none; width: 200px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer; }
.escondido:checked + label .imagem { display: block; }

.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: blue; }
.c { background-color: green; }
.d { background-color: yellow; }

.mini { display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 5px; }

.escondido.a:checked ~ label .mini.a { border: 2px solid black; }
.escondido.b:checked ~ label .mini.b { border: 2px solid black; }
.escondido.c:checked ~ label .mini.c { border: 2px solid black; }
.escondido.d:checked ~ label .mini.d { border: 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<!-- Imagens -->
<input id="img1" class="escondido a" type="radio" name="imgs" checked>
<label for="img2"><div class="imagem a"></div></label>

<input id="img2" class="escondido b" type="radio" name="imgs">
<label for="img3"><div class="imagem b"></div></label>

<input id="img3" class="escondido c" type="radio" name="imgs">
<label for="img4"><div class="imagem c"></div></label>

<input id="img4" class="escondido d" type="radio" name="imgs">
<label for="img1"><div class="imagem d"></div></label>

<!-- Miniaturas -->
<label for="img1"><div class="imagem mini a"></div></label>
<label for="img2"><div class="imagem mini b"></div></label>
<label for="img3"><div class="imagem mini c"></div></label>
<label for="img4"><div class="imagem mini d"></div></label>
```

Eu gostaria agora de animar a transição entre os estados "exibido" e "ocultado". Sei que não é possível animar a propriedade `display` diretamente: o jQuery por exemplo na hora de mostrar primeiro reduz o tamanho do elemento pra zero, passa o `display` de "escondido" pra "exibido", então anima o tamanho do elemento de zero até seu tamanho real. Eu não posso fazer algo semelhante só com CSS, pois não dá pra dizer "primeiro faça isso, depois faça aquilo"...

Tentei evitar o `display` e simplesmente colocar a altura total da `div` em zero. Funcionou bem se a `div` possui tamanho fixo, mas não se o tamanho é variável (ela "saltou" direto entre os tamanhos zero e máximo):

```css
.escondido { display: none; }
.box { height: 0; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; transition: height 2s; }

h2 { width: 200px; background-color: lightgray; cursor: pointer; }
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: lightgray; }

.escondido:checked + .a { display: block; height: 100px; }
.escondido:checked + .b { display: block; height: auto; }
```

```html
<label for="aba1"><h2>funciona</h2></label>
<input id="aba1" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box a"></div>

<label for="aba2"><h2>não funciona</h2></label>
<input id="aba2" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

(tentei também com `max-height`, e funcionou igualmente na `div` de tamanho fixo, mas nesse caso a de tamanho variável nem foi exibida...)

É possível fazer isso somente com CSS, sem precisar especificar um tamanho absoluto? (e sem comprometer a responsividade, i.e. se ao ajustar a largura da janela a altura da `div` mudar, que continue funcionando) Que propriedades eu poderia tentar animar para criar a ilusão de "escondido/exibido" com transição suave?

Nota: no caso das imagens, a troca seria horizontal e não vertical, mas como é mais fácil lidar com imagens (pois usualmente seu tamanho é conhecido) esse caso pode ficar de fora da pergunta (mas sugestões pra esse caso também seriam muito bem vindas).

Answer (score 8):

Há uns tempos para cá eu criei [um artigo](http://tedcss.blogspot.pt/2015/08/menu-deslizante-transicao-height-0-para-auto.html) sobre este mesmo assunto no meu Blog.
Podes fazer isso utilizando o `max-height` da seguinte maneira:

```
.box { max-height: 0; transition: max-height 2s;}
.escondido:checked + .b { max-height:100px; }
```

Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.escondido { display: none; }
.box { max-height: 0; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; transition: max-height 2s; }

h2 { width: 200px; background-color: lightgray; cursor: pointer; }
.b { background-color: lightgray; }

.escondido:checked + .b { display: block; max-height:100px; }
```

```html
<label for="aba2"><h2>Seção 2</h2></label>
<input id="aba2" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

Comment: Mas ai vai cortar o texto se for maior, não?

Comment: sim, mas pode-se definir um `max-height` maior, o único problema é que ao fazer isso a transição vai ser afetada por estar agora a calcular para uma altura maior

Comment: Como o @Bacco comentou, a menos que eu coloque um `max-height` grande o suficiente pra garantir que o conteúdo nunca será maior que ele, pode ocorrer *overflow*... Engraçado que eu já tinha tentado isso, mas não havia funcionado, mas seu exemplo funciona. O maior problema é (isso que vc acabou de comentar... :P)

Comment: De todo modo, +1, pois usando um *easing* adequado essa solução pode ser boa o bastante na ausência de outras.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz uma experiência utilizando função scaleY do transform junto na transição, o efeito não é o mesmo mas "resolve" a questão do height relativo. De repente pode servir como ponto de partida para uma solução realmente definitiva.

```css
.escondido { display: none;}
.box {  
  height:0px;
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transform-origin: top;
  
  width: 200px; overflow: auto;  
  transition: transform 1s, height 1s;
 
  }

h2 { width: 200px; background-color: lightgray; cursor: pointer; }
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: lightgray; }


.escondido:checked + .a { display: block; transform: scaleY(1); height:100px; }
.escondido:checked + .b { display: block; transform: scaleY(1); height: 100%; }
```

```html
<label for="aba1"><h2>funciona</h2></label>
<input id="aba1" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box a"></div>

<label for="aba2"><h2>quase funciona</h2></label>
<input id="aba2" class="escondido" type="checkbox">
<div class="box b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom! Para o efeito ficar menos "feio", é só animar também o `opacity` de `0` (quando a `div` está escondida) até `1` (quando está exibida), assim no intervalo em que o conteúdo está mais "espremido" ele também estará quase invisível. Não vou marcar como aceita pois como você mesmo disse não é uma solução definitiva, mas já que você resolveu meu maior problema (a altura relativa) a recompensa é sua! :)

Comment: Realmente @mgibsonbr, essa definitivamente não é solução que merece ser marcada como resposta. Agradeço muito a recompensa, trabalho há mais de 15 anos com desenvolvimento web mas fiz minha conta faz pouco tempo. Vi muitas perguntas que eu poderia ter contribuído para solução, mas não tinha o privilégio de poder comentar  solicitando algum esclarecimento. Obrigado mesmo.